# How to leave enough space for handwriting notes in twocolumn pages

Tags: pdftex, margins, notes

I would like to leave enough margin spaces in the pages to be able to make hand annotations in the PDF file.
The document has `twocolumns` and is generated with IEEEtran document class.

For example:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
% The preceding line is only needed to identify funding in the first footnote. If that is unneeded, please comment it out.
\usepackage{cite}
% \usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
  \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../pdf/}{../jpeg/}}
  \graphicspath{{./figs/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png}
\else
  % or other class option (dvipsone, dvipdf, if not using dvips). graphicx
  % will default to the driver specified in the system graphics.cfg if no
  % driver is specified.
  \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
  % declare the path(s) where your graphic files are
  % \graphicspath{{../eps/}}
  \graphicspath{{./figs/}}
  % and their extensions so you won't have to specify these with
  % every instance of \includegraphics
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\fi

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
    \begin{abstract}

    \blindtext

    \end{abstract}

    \Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

will produce a document which the first page is

[image]

The text covers most of the page. I would like to keep the `twocolumns` structure but to have more space for handwriting annotations.

Regards

Comment: Have you considered to show us a short compilable code and add an screenshot of your result to your question, marking there where you want to get space for handwriting? As far as it stands now your question is very unclear ...

Comment: This could be done using the `geometry` package. (for example `\usepackage[right=4cm, left=4cm,top=1.75cm, bottom=1.75cm]{geometry}`) However, this will make your columns quite small.

Comment: @leandris I have tested your geometry line widen the margins. I would like to keep the columns text as they are but change the size of the page (left and right sides) to have more note-taking space. Regards

Comment: most publisher classes (like ieeetran) are explictly designed to remove choice from the author, if you change the page layout it may complicate submission to an IEEE journal (however you can decrease \oddsidemargin and increase \evensidemargin

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do not want to make a paper print I just would like to have the PDF in electronic with more space to write with an apple pencil.

Comment: sure, but choosing a publisher class makes customisation harder, as that is what they are designed to do:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right. Thank you. I have tried `\documentclass[conference,a3paper]{IEEEtran}` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
 \addtolength\oddsidemargin{1cm}
```

[image]